# Java - How can I assign lots of colors simply?

Tags: java

I just wanted to know if there was a way of making this code simpler.
Thanks.

```
private void btnBlueActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    btnConvert.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(84, 209, 241)); //Changes the colors to blue
    btnReset.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(84, 209, 241));   //Changes the colors to blue
    btnClose.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(84, 209, 241));   //Changes the colors to blue
    btnInfo.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(84, 209, 241));    //Changes the colors to blue

    txtIncome.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(127, 228, 255)); //Changes the colors to blue
    txtPayable.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(127, 228, 255));//Changes the colors to blue
    txtStatus.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(127, 228, 255)); //Changes the colors to blue
    txtIncome.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(89, 89, 89));    //Changes the colors to blue
    txtPayable.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(89, 89, 89));   //Changes the colors to blue
    txtStatus.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(89, 89, 89));    //Changes the colors to blue
}
```

Comment: Use constants. Create variables for each of those and re-use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of re-creating the same color over and over you could just create each one once, and then assign them as necessary:

```
Color btnColor = new Color(84, 209, 241);
Color txtColor1 = new Color(127, 228, 255);
Color textcolor2 = new Color(89, 89, 89);
```

Then:

```
private void btnBlueActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    btnConvert.setBackground(btnColor);                                    
    btnReset.setBackground(btnColor);                                      
    btnClose.setBackground(btnColor);                                      
    btnInfo.setBackground(btnColor);                                       
    txtIncome.setBackground(txtColor1);                                    
    txtPayable.setBackground(txtColor1);                                   
    txtStatus.setBackground(txtColor1);                                    
    txtIncome.setForeground(textcolor2);                                       
    txtPayable.setForeground(textcolor2);                                      
    txtStatus.setForeground(textcolor2);                                        
}
```

Comment: OP should note that they have to add `import java.awt.*;` to the top of their file.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your objects should actually be parts of collections that are grouped together.

```
// assuming "mainMenuButtons" (or whatever) contains your first four objects
// note I don't know what color (84, 209, 241) actually is
for(Button btn : mainMenuButtons) {
    btn.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(84, 209, 241));
}
```

Secondly those colors are immutable. There's no need to create so many objects

```
Color reddish = new java.awt.Color(84, 209, 241);
// then just use reddish everywhere instead of creating a new color each time.
```

Answer (score 0):

To simplify both the code and changes you may want to make in the future, do the following:

1. Create a container for components that should share the same foreground or background
2. Create a container for colors (indexed by state)
3. Make a small ComponentUtil Class that lets you change colors for all members of a container

When an action changes the state of the components, you pick up the correct color for the component and call ComponentUtil.setBackground(components, color); or ComponentUtil.setForeground(components, color);

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
public class ComponentUtil {

public static void setBackground(Component[] components, Color color) {
    for (int i=0; i < components.length; i++) {
        components[i].setBackground(color);
    }
}

public static void setForeground(Component[] components, Color color) {
    for (int i=0; i < components.length; i++) {
        components[i].setForeground(color);
    }
}
}
```